# textbox value with hard coded dash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox in the page. `<input type="text" id="cell">`

I have used below jquery....

```
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cell").keypress(function () {
        i += 1;
        if (i == 4) {
            var cellValue = $("#cell").val() + "-";
            $("#cell").val(cellValue);
        }
    });
});
```

whenever an user types `12345678` (or any number) it automatically shows `123-45678`. But problem is when user uses backspace or delete and then starts typing `12345678` it does not show `123-45678`. Please help

Comment: I'd recommend applying the formatting on blur rather than on keypress. That way you don't have to worry about what happens if the user moves the cursor to the middle of the field, or deletes, or pastes values without even using the keyboard, etc.

Comment: your code is not working...nothing is happening

Comment: @nnnnnn: at this position in time your name is `nnnnnn` and your rep is `44444` - that's awesome!  ;o)

Comment: @Westie his name is 6 chars length his rep is 5

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy: No!  Don't spoil the moment!  ;o)

Comment: Thanks @Westie. Yes, if I get any more upvotes I'm going to have to start posting some nonsense to get balancing downvotes so I can retain the `44444`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` should be the length of the value , not the number of times you pressed the key

Try this -

```
$("#cell").keypress(function () {
    i = $(this).val().length;
    if (i == 3) {
        var cellValue = $("#cell").val() + "-";
        $("#cell").val(cellValue);
    }
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/KZmc9/2/

Comment: In your demo you cannot delete the first 3 digits (before -)

Comment: but in my page, it does not remove first three numbers like (123). I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cell").keypress(function(){
        if (this.value.length == 3) {
            $("#cell").val(this.value + "-");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cv6HL/)

Comment: this is working fine. but it does not remove last three characters.

Comment: what do you mean by `it does not remove last three characters`?

Comment: If you try to delete the first 3 characters using the backspace.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, now you can delete all digits (if you hold backspace), but if you try to delete one by one (by pressing backspace for each character) the dash disappears and is added again :P

Answer (score 0):

I would split the input into two, because otherwise users have to delete the dash if they want to delete the 3rd number.

http://jsfiddle.net/TATnK/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cell_1').on('input', function(e) {
        if($(this).val().length == 3) {
            $('#cell_2').focus();
        }
    });

    $('#cell_2').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 8 && $(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('#cell_1').focus();            
        }
    });
});
```